# Multiple listview objects at the same position

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a chart with multiple chart areas and I want to have a listview where the user checks different signals, that are being plotted in the areas.
Since I want some signals to be displayed in more than one chart areas, I need the listview to reset every time the user selects a different chart Area.

To achieve this I think it is a good idea to create a new listview every time the user selects another chart area and bring the new to front.

My question is , how can I create multiple listviews at the exact same location, and also if someone has a better idea to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, you can define the listview in code and do all the styling by hand or you can create a customControl for that.
But then, when the load event of your main form is fired, you create all the listview/customListViewObjects that you need and place them in the same location with the same size by setting their `Location` and `Size` property. Finally, you can use `BrintToFront()` on the required listview when an area is selected.

There are some other ways, but they aren't beautiful in winforms.

A) you can create a tab control with N tabs, then place a listview in each tab and set the tabControl style to the tab header/title is not shown. But as far as I remember, the tabControl will add a border frame that your cannot get rid of.

B) If you don't have many areas and its number is not going to change, you can create the listviews manually in your form editor, and place them wherever in your form (with the appropriate parent, of course). Then in your load event, you can set their location and size properties to the one you need. This is kind of ugly and you may see the controls moving when the form is loaded if you are not careful.

On the other hand, you can just have one listview and then, when the area is clicked you can reload all its child controls for the different signals.